Can my `.clang-format` include another `.clang-format`?
I have a project with some sub-projects, and want clang-format to sort them differently depending on sub-project. Can I have the sub-projects "include" a top-level .clang-format file?
(Searches for this always seem to bring up how I can configure the order of #include directives, which isn't what I want!)

In base directory you should provide your default .clang-format.
Now based on documentation (didn't test this):


InheritParentConfig Not a real style, but allows to use the .clang-format file from the parent directory (or its parent if there is none). If there is no parent file found it falls back to the fallback style, and applies the changes to that.
With this option you can overwrite some parts of your main style for your subdirectories. This is also possible through the command line, e.g.: --style={BasedOnStyle: InheritParentConfig, ColumnLimit: 20}


You can add an extra .clang-format file in sub-directories where you wish to have small changes in configuration with BasedOnStyle set to InheritParentConfig and with settings altered for your needs (like preferred header sorting).
